# How to escape $ in a travis ci encrypted environment variable?

Tags: travis-ci

Travis CI's user documentation has a [section](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Note-on-escaping-certain-symbols) on how to escape secure environment variables. It seems not to work for the '$' symbol. Is there anything special that needs done for the '$' symbol?

I setup this example. In .travis.yml:

```
travis encrypt "FAKE_PASSWORD=H3llo\\#Worl\\$d" -a
```

In my script I echo the variable and get:

```
fake password is H3llo#Worl
```

It appears that `$d` is being replaced with nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when running `travis encrypt` the `$` symbol needs to be escaped for the command as well as when the variable is used. With two backslashes `\\` it only creates one backslash in the variable and `$d` is still expanded by bash. Using three backslashes fixes the issue.

```
travis encrypt "FAKE_PASSWORD=H3llo\\#Worl\\\$d" -a
```

`\\` creates a single backslash and `\$` creates a $ symbol that is not expanded by bash. When travis runs the bash command to create that variable looks like

```
FAKE_PASSWORD=H3llo\\#World\$d
```

This is what bash expects when using a `$` in a variable.